# How to Replace URL Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

On my blog site my homepage have all my posts. If I click on any post it will lead me to https://my-domain.com/xyz-post(for example). I want to replace this url(on click/before click) to another website's url directory Like this.

> https://my-domain.com/xyz-post to https://new-domain.com/blog/xyz-post

I want this for all my posts in bulk. Redirection won't solve my problem.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: please add your current code...

Comment: use links <a> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a